# Is context.clearRect() necessary?

Tags: javascript, canvas

My application is a bit slow. I believe this is because `.clearRect` is one of the more intensive events in my application so far. However I also draw an image on top of the screen (as background) at the top of each loop, like this:

```
function redraw(){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.clientWidth,canvas.clientHeight);
  ctx.drawImage(background,0,0,canvas.clientWidth,canvas.clientHeight);

  var i=0,l=objects.length;
  while(i<l){
    objects[i].redraw();
    i++
  }
  ctx.restore();
}
```

I'd like to improve the speed of this code. Would removing the `.clearRect` call be a good way to optimize performance? Or will this clog up memory?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple yes/no question and not a review of the code.

Comment: @Malachi Just because the underlying question is a simple yes/no question doesn't mean that the code can't be reviewed.

Comment: Agreed @SimonAndréForsberg, but the OP should know that these questions are off topic so they don't slide down the wrong side of the hill.

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully make it seem more on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it's phrased, this isn't really a Code Review question. Still, I'll try to treat it as one.

But first, to answer your question: Yes, I would imagine you could just remove the call to `clearRect` as long as the background image you're drawing is entirely opaque.

(incidentally, you should just be able to try it out and see quicker than asking question on a Stack Exchange site: Just comment out the line and see what happens.)

However, in code review terms, I have to wonder *why* you're drawing the image on every update. If the background image doesn't constantly change, you could just consider keeping the `clearRect` call, but setting the background image as a regular CSS background on the canvas element. Then you don't need to worry about drawing the background yourself; it'll just be there, behind the canvas element.

Also, what's with the `while` loop? You've just written a complicated equivalent to a `for`-loop. Given its purpose here, a `for` loop would by far be the most straightforward thing to use:

```
for(var i = 0, l = objects.length ; i < l ; i++) {
  objects[i].redraw();
}
```

While you're at it, please give your code some room to breathe. Apart from indentation, I don't see a single space anywhere in your code. It's all squished together, which makes it unnecessarilyhardtoread.

And you're missing a semi-colon in the `while` loop. JS will still run your code, but I see no reason to rely on JS's automatic semi-colon insertion. Especially not on the one line that must work to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: I personally find while loops more logical than for loops, and is it really bad to rely on JS's automatic semi-colons? It feels cleaner to me.

Comment: @JacobPedersen My gut feeling is that you're in the minority with regard to using `while` loops for iterating fixed-length arrays. In the end, both your `while` loop, and my `for` loop will end up as the exact same CPU instructions, but they both exist for the benefit of humans reading the code. And in this case - iterating an array with a known length - a `for` loop is _by far_ the most conventional way to write it.

Comment: If it comes down to preference, I'll stick to while loops. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @JacobPedersen As for the auto-semicolons: Yeah, it may look cleaner, but since you can't leave out semis _everywhere_, it implies that the language _does_ need them. JS specifically does do semi-colon _insertion_, because it's more or less trying to fix your "mistakes". Personally, I'd prefer my code to just be mistake-free to begin with.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll insert them properly.

Comment: @JacobPedersen Sure, you can stick with `while` loops _as long as you're only coding for yourself._ I just spent paragraph and a comment on saying how the `while` loop was a pretty unconventional choice here, and basically made me go "huh?" and furrow my brow. So even if you prefer it, just know that other people may just find it strange and/or wrong. A common source of infinite loops is forgetting the `i++`; it's a lot harder to make that blunder with a `for`-loops syntax because they follow a set pattern.

Comment: Right. I'll keep that in mind.